Is there a way to roughly estimate efficiency of antenna?
I have a NanoVNA and a spectrum analyzer with a tracking generator. Is there a way I could set up a quick and dirty experiment to roughly estimate the efficiency of UHF antenna I have built?
I am thinking of using some reference antenna with known and stable efficiency to compare against, but I wander if someone already did this?

What kind of antenna have you made?

Efficiency is a slippery term.  Efficiency for what?  Does this include radiation pattern, size, aperture, or just energy loss?
Let's narrow this to assume you just care about energy loss.
The efficiency of the antenna would be radiation resistance vs. loss resistance.  You can't measure radiation resistance with a VNA or spectrum analyzer.  You can estimate it with a field strength meter or model it.  (Probably need to do both.)
You might be able to guess at loss resistance by measuring DC resistance and impedance mismatch.  (The VNA might be able to give useful numbers there.)
As an example, a small loop (less than 1/4 wavelength in circumference with a tuning capacitor in series opposite the feed point) typically has a (modeled) radiation resistance around 0.1 ohm.   So any loss in the antenna will severely impact performance.  This includes DC wire resistance (so use high conductivity pipe with a big surface area), contact resistance in the capacitor (so use a butterfly cap with no contacts) and ESR of any dielectric in the capacitor (so use a vacuum variable or an air gap cap).   All of these losses can be measured in components individually.  (Small loops are notorious for low efficiency, but make up for it with high directionality and very low noise due to their instantaneous narrow bandwidth (high Q) and wide frequency agility due to the tuning capacitor.)
